# Help with spinor indices

Tags: matrices, physics, spin-geometry

Let's have
$$
\varepsilon^{\alpha \beta} = \varepsilon^{\dot {\alpha }\dot {\beta }} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^{\alpha \beta}, \quad \varepsilon^{\alpha \beta} = -\varepsilon_{\alpha \beta},
$$
which represents the metric of 2-spinor $\psi_{\alpha}$:
$$
\psi^{\alpha \dot {\beta }} = \varepsilon^{\alpha \gamma}\varepsilon^{\dot {\beta }\dot {\delta}}\psi_{\gamma \dot {\delta}}.
$$

Then let's have Pauli matrices:
$$
\hat {\sigma}_{0} = \hat {\mathbf E}, \quad \hat {\sigma}_{1} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad \hat {\sigma}_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -i \\ i & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad \hat {\sigma}_{3} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then - let's have the definition
$$
(\tilde {\sigma}^{\mu})^{\dot {\beta } \beta } = \varepsilon^{\beta \gamma}\varepsilon^{\dot {\beta} \dot {\gamma}}(\sigma^{\mu})_{\gamma \dot {\gamma }} = \left( \hat {\mathbf E }, -\hat {\mathbf \sigma } \right).
$$
So, how to show that
$$
\varepsilon^{\dot {\alpha} \dot {\beta }}(\sigma^{\mu})_{\alpha \dot {\alpha}}(\sigma^{\nu})_{\beta \dot {\beta }} = (\sigma^{\mu}\tilde {\sigma}^{\nu})_{\alpha \beta}?
$$

**Addition**.

I made it (look at the end of the question): https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75360/spinor-indices-and-antisymmetric-tensor .

Comment: Try it in two parts:  first you know that $\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta}$ is an invariant tensor (which is why it's admissible to use it to lower and raise indices in a meaningful way).  You've given the components for $\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta}$ and $\varepsilon_{\alpha\beta}$.  How about $\varepsilon^\alpha{}_\beta$?  Once you have that, why not use $\varepsilon$ to raise the $\alpha$ on both sides of your final equation?

Comment: Another way to think about all of this is to use the Lie algebra isomorphism ${\rm so}(4) \simeq {\rm su}(2) \times {\rm su}(2)$ and $\alpha$ as the index on $(1/2,0)$, $\dot\alpha$ on $(0,1/2)$ and $\mu$ on $(1/2,1/2)$.  Then $\sigma^\mu{}_{\alpha\dot\alpha}$ projects $(1/2,1/2) \times (1/2,0) \times (0,1/2)$ onto the trivial representation $(0,0)$.

Comment: @josh . I think that calculation will be done without $\varepsilon^{\alpha}_{\quad \beta}$. But I have only small experience in spinor calculus. I tried to prove it yecterday by two attempts.

Comment: @josh . My first attempt gave
$$
\varepsilon^{\dot {\alpha } \dot {\beta } } (\sigma^{\mu})_{\alpha \dot {\alpha}}(\sigma^{\nu})_{\beta \dot {\beta}} = (\sigma^{\mu})_{\alpha \dot {\alpha}}(\sigma^{\nu})_{\beta }^{\quad \dot {\alpha}} = (\sigma^{\mu})_{\alpha \dot {\alpha}}\varepsilon_{\beta \delta}(\sigma^{\nu})^{\delta \dot {\alpha}} = (\sigma^{\mu }\tilde {\sigma }^{\nu})^{\quad \delta}_{\alpha}\varepsilon_{\beta \delta} = (\sigma^{\mu }\tilde {\sigma }^{\nu})_{\alpha \beta }.
$$

Comment: Bit the second gave
$$
\varepsilon^{\dot {\alpha } \dot {\beta } } (\sigma^{\mu})_{\alpha \dot {\alpha}}(\sigma^{\nu})_{\beta \dot {\beta}} = (\sigma^{\mu})_{\alpha}^{\quad \dot {\beta }}(\sigma^{\nu})_{\beta \dot {\beta}} = -(\sigma^{\mu})_{\alpha \dot {\beta }}(\sigma^{\nu})_{\beta}^{\quad \dot {\beta}} = -(\sigma^{\mu }\tilde {\sigma }^{\nu})_{\alpha \beta },
$$
so it show that I'm confused and work with indices bad. Do you see where I made the mistake?

Comment: @josh . Also, $\varepsilon^{\alpha}_{\quad \beta} = \delta^{\alpha}_{\quad \beta}$ isn't invariant under transformations.

Comment: Are you sure the Kronecker $\delta$ is not invariant?  Tell me in which frame it has the usual 0 and 1 components, then.  What does it look like in another frame?